# Rails getting started wizard in separate controller from users controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wizard, controllers

I have a Rails site that requires a lot of form fields that need to be filled out after the user first signs up (using a large jQuery wizard).  At first, I wrapped all the "getting started" (executed when the user logs in for the first time) specific code in the users controller like this:

```
Class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
  def getting_started



 def getting_started
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    unless @user.employees.length == 15
      15.times { @user.employees.build }
    end
  end
end
```

My question is, should I separate out the getting started method into it's own controller if the getting started method is beginning to grow rather large?  What is the "rails way" of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Size isn't what dictates a new controller--controller *purpose* dictates a new controller. If it's not related to a `User` and is entity-like on its own, new controller. If it's just more `User` data, it should stay.

If it's simple *size* you're concerned with, it depends. If it's code acting directly on a `User`, it may belong in the `User` model. If not, it belong in `private` methods or its own library.

Without further details regarding what `getting_started` actually does, it's difficult to be more specific.

Comment: Getting started in a nutshell uses the build method to create a certain numbers of employees.  (Each user has many employees).  The getting_started method basically preps for the getting started wizard form creation.  Mainly it prepares other nested attributes for use in a giant form.  Since it is mixing many of these different controllers such as employees, would it go in it's own separate controller?

Comment: @Flashuni doesn't sound like a controller if it's not interacting with the web layer, sounds more like you need helpers/utilities. Still unclear, though.